# is it possible to SIGNAL without invoking a rollback? on db2?

Tags: sql, db2

is it possible to SIGNAL without invoking a rollback (i.e. is there SQLSTATE that does not cause a rollback), or does SIGNAL automatically infer a rollback?

I have a query

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEAD_TRAILERS_NOTIFY
AFTER UPDATE OF TRAILER ON TRIP 
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE DEAD_SAT VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE MSG VARCHAR(70); 

SET DEAD_SAT = COALESCE((SELECT TRAILER_ID FROM TRAILER WHERE LAST_SAT_DATE < CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 8 DAYS AND N.TRAILER = TRAILER_ID),'OK');



    IF DEAD_SAT <> 'OK' AND USER NOT IN ('VISTAR','TM4WIN') THEN
    SET MSG = 'SAT ON TRAILER IS DEAD. PLEASE GET IT REPLACED'; 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '90001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = MSG;
    END IF;
END
```

Only problem is if it fails to meet the trigger it rolls the data back. Is there a SQL state that doesn't do this or do they all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an SQLSTATE that signifies a warning rather than an exception.

The first two characters need to be 01.

For user defined warnings, use
`01Hxx  Valid warning SQLSTATEs returned by a user-defined function or external procedure CALL.`

Where xx is whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn set the `autocommit` property to `false` for your application's connection to the database, and implement proper error handling in the application. When you catch an error, you can decide whether to `commit` (like if SQLSTATE = '90001') or `rollback` (other errors).

However, keep in mind that if your application is written such that it never issues explicit `commit` statements, you may create other concurrency or logging issues.

Answer (score 0):

The `SIGNAL` statement by itself does not cause a rollback; it is the client (caller) handling the signal that does that. For example, if you do your `UPDATE` from a Java program, it will get an `SQLException`, and it's up to the programmer to observe the `SQLSTATE` value and act accordingly.